# Xorg repeatedly tried to add built-in webcam as keyboard

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, webcam

First time poster here. I'm having a problem with `xorg` and my laptop Dell Inspiron 15 7537 running Ubuntu 15.10. I'm not configuring the nvidia GT750M in my system so no nvidia stuff at all in my computer. I'm running the latest **Intel graphic firmware** as installed by Intel graphic installer app.

The **first symptom** is after using the computer for 2 or 3 days all the graphics animation start to lag very badly, including chrome and playing YouTube video. When i checked via '`top`' command, xorg idles with 30% cpu usage, and when browsing web with chrome, something as simple as scrolling the web page would make xorg jump to 100% cpu usage. I thought it was the built in intel driver that is causing this. So i tried updating it to the latest version but the issues remains.

Then i tried checking the `xorg log` located at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for some clue, and i found something weird, Xorg repeatedly tried to add an input device called  "`Integrated_Webcam_HD`" as a keyboard

```
[359929.951] (II) config/udev: Adding input device     Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event13)
[359929.951] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[359929.951] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Integrated_Webcam_HD'
[359929.951] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: always reports core events
[359929.951] (**) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Device: "/dev/input/event13"
[359929.951] (--) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Vendor 0xc45 Product 0x6a00
[359929.951] (--) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Found keys
[359929.951] (II) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Configuring as keyboard
[359929.951] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input6735/event13"
[359929.951] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Integrated_Webcam_HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[359929.951] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[359929.951] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[359929.951] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[359929.951] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[359929.951] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[359930.507] (II) config/udev: removing device Integrated_Webcam_HD
[359930.520] (II) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Close
[359930.520] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
```

my `xorg.log` file was completely filled with that log repeating itself over and over. I thought this was the cause, so i search the internet for way to disable the Webcam as i don't use it. I found this guide here 
https://superuser.com/questions/335687/disabling-an-dev-inputx-input-device-on-ubuntu-linux

and I did all the steps by adding a rule to ignore the webcam, restart my laptop and now the log looks like this:

```
[   969.406] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event14)
[   969.406] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Ignoring device from InputClass "disable broken device"
[   970.577] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event14)
[   970.577] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Ignoring device from InputClass "disable broken device"
[   971.729] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event14)
[   971.729] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Ignoring device from InputClass "disable broken device"
[   972.901] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event14)
```

also repeating itself over and over again. I believe this will also cause some problems down in the line.
Do anybody have solution for this ?

Comment: can you show `xinput list` please.